# the meaning and grammar of 'as hard as it takes' in this sentence

Tags: comparison

This is the subs below from TV show *Suits*

> Harvey"Let me tell you something. This isn’t elementary school. This is hard work. Long hours. High pressure. I need a grown goddamn man."
>     Mike "You give me this, and I will work **as hard as it takes to school** those Harvard douches and become the best lawyer you have ever seen."

I think I know that the bold part is 'as ~as comparison'.
However, the part I don't get is why 'takes' is used in the sentence.

The reason I get to wonder is... Please look at the sentence below.

> a) It’s not **as heavy as** I thought it would be, actually.

If the sentence a) is separated into two parts, it will be like...

> It is not heavy. I thought it would be heavy.

Based on this rule, if Mike's sentence is divided, I think it will be like this.

> I will work hard. **It takes hard(?)** to school those Harvard douches.

If the words come after 'takes' I thought it is supposed to be 'hard work'

Thus, if I separated Mike's phrasing,

> I will work hard. **It is hard to school** those Harvard douches.
>   or
>   I will work hard. **It takes hard work to school** those Harvard douches.

By any chance, is 'as hard as it takes' idiomatic?

It is hard to analyze and understand for me as not a native English speaker.
It has been annoying me for days...
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: It's a misstatement of an idiom, _as long as it takes_. This is from the construction _take_ + <time length>, as in _This'll take a while, Take a minute to look at it, Take all the time you need, It usually takes a half-hour, You should keep going as long as it takes to do the job_. This is substituting degree of work (on a scale where _hard_ is a large degree) for time, which doesn't really work with the verb _take_.  You can't use _hard_ like _long_; it doesn't mean the same, and it's not part of the idiom. It **sounds** like it might make sense, but it's just off pitch.

Answer (score 1):

- I will work as hard as **it takes to school those Harvard douches**

Based on: **It takes hard work** to school those Harvard douches.

The parse is: as hard as it takes **to do something**.

The parse is not: "as hard as it takes" on its own.

**It takes hard work** **to do something.**= to school [verb] those Harvard douches.

takes is used because it refers to: It takes hard work to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis seems OK to me. And yes, the phrase *”as hard as it takes”* is idiomatic. But it’s not very common. I threw it at Google Ngram and it found a few instances, but all recent and not too many of them.

But notice that it has the same form as *“as **long** as it takes”*, and that is much more common.

Comment: I believe the idea is that the task takes (consumes) time.